# IE9 CSS hack for background-position?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I need an IE9 CSS hack to be able to set the background-position property differently for IE9.

I have tried with several different ones that didn't work and from what I read somewhere, the background property is not possible to "hack" at least the same way as the other.

I basically need this to only apply to IE9:

```
#ABB_ABContent .subnav li.selected { background-position: center 17px; }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can put IE9 specific styles in a separate stylesheet and include it using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx).

Comment: Why would you want to have a different background position for IE9? What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Well, the problem is that in IE9 the background element is displayed 1px lower than in the other browsers I tested on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find anything else, there's always conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
IE9-specific code goes here
<![endif]-->
```

This would have to live in your HTML code, rather than your stylesheet, but you could use it to include an additional CSS file for IE9.

Alternatively, you may want to look up the [Modernizr library](http://www.modernizr.com/). This is a small Javascript tool which you add to your site, which detects what features your browser supports, and allows you to write your CSS to target specific features (or their absence). If there's something about IE9 that it doesn't support which you're trying to work around, this may be the best solution.

I'm still puzzled as to what problem you're trying to solve though.

Comment: You can wrap the comments around a `<style>.foo { yada: yada; }</style>` section.

Comment: @Salman: indeed you can, but it would still be in the main page code, rather than being in a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--[if IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your path" />
 <![endif]-->
```